# HTML Input Type Number

Tags: html, input, numbers

```
<label for="inputNumber">Number</label><br />
<input type="number" name="inputNumber" id="inputNumber" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sumit" />
```

I want Input Type Number to accept comma as decimal seperator.
It allows comma in firefox but when submit button is clicked comma is not validated as valid value.
OR 2nd option
because i have created this form for german users and they will be using german keyboard. and  i want that :
if comma is pressed to input decimal seperator input:number accets it as period "."
and then people will enter comma from their num-pad decimal seperator "," and in input a period will be entered "."

I hope you get my question :
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `step`?
`<input type="number" step="any" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <input type="number" name="price" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01">
```

Comment: pattern doesnt work with number type to accept "," i have added input type="text" and pattern and it works fine